# Is there any way I can mess with the TCP stack in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, tcp, winsock

I want to send a TCP ack packet a certain number of bytes ahead of the data that I have actually recieved in order to "resume" a download. I would also need to change the state of the TCP stack to be in synch with this ack.

One possible solution to doing this would be to gain direct control over lower level interfaces and transmit my own TCP packets using my own stack, however, this would be an inferior solution to using the windows TCP stack. Does anyone know how I can affect the windows tcp stack to do this?

Comment: That will not have the effect you are seeking, and it would be a violation of the RFCs.

Comment: This is like one of those answers where people say: "The result of such an operation is undefined." Well, all that means is that it can be one of multiple ways. However, it may still work. My responsibility is to test IF it works and handle it if not. Some TCP stacks may well work as I am expecting them to.

Comment: This is like one of those questions where people say 'it may still work', so (a) how do I do it, and (b) why doesn't it work?' RFC 793 clearly defines what you are proposing as an 'unacceptable ACK'. So why on earth are you asking this question, and what exactly is the basis for your belief that it will have any effect on your requirement?

Comment: Yes and the html standard specifies that only void elements can be self closed...

Comment: Yes and so what exactly? You still haven't produced any evidence or reasoning to show that what you are attempting will actually accomplish your objective.

Comment: Thats the whole point, I want to try it to see if it can work!

Comment: And that's the whole point, I am saving you the trouble. It won't work. I can't imagine what you think a TCP/IP stack is going to do when it receives an acknowledgement for a byte number it hasn't sent yet, and why and how that is going to solve your upload resume problem, but the RFC dictates that such an ACK packet is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, that sounds like a recipe for connection failures. What happens if that ACK arrives at the sender before it sends the bytes that you're ACK-ing?

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It explains the rationale for not providing such an interface in WinSock. There's really no need for a "`BreakConnectionRandomly(BOOL OnlyAtCustomerSite)`"

Comment: @slcpfmmm answer is not at all irrelevant.

Comment: It is irrelevant. I clearly asked how to affect the stack, not whether or not I should.

Comment: @chacham15 nevertheless the null hypothesis is always relevant.